# Numerical Laplace transform python

Tags: python, numpy, transform

I have a time series of experimental data x = x(t) in two numpy arrays, x for the observable and t for the time values of the observations. Is there a numpy function or a way that can evaluate the laplace transform of the timeseries? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A Laplace transform is a (improper) integral, so you could try a number of numerical integration methods. It all depends on what values you have in the time variable (a regular grid, some random values,...?). Please give more details in your question, including a sample of your data if possible.

Comment: I have a regular grid with equally spaced points in space and in time (x-t plain). I want to make a Laplace transform of a selected x position time series. A small part of such a time series has x = [16.8024
16.8241
16.8847
16.9335
16.9139
17.0433
17.0429
17.2464
17.3340
17.4839] while t = [200.0496
200.1925
200.3354
200.4783
200.6212
200.7641
200.9071
201.0500
201.1929
201.3358
] Hope that helps

Answer (score 9):

I think you should have to consider the Laplace Transform of f(x) as the Fourier Transform of Gamma(x)f(x)e^(bx), in which Gamma is a step function that delete the negative part of the integral and e^(bx) constitute the real part of the complex exponential.
There is a well known algorithm for Fourier Transform known as "Fast Fourier Transform" (FFT), for which you can find a lot of tutorials on both Python and Matlab websites.

Here I give you a short code that calculate the Fourier transform of a step function such as
y = 0 for |x| > 1
y = 1 for |x| < 1

for which the Fourier Transform can be analitically calculated as sin(pi*x) / (pi*x).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy.fftpack import fftshift
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
y = np.zeros(len(x))
y[150:450] = 1
plt.plot(x, y) # plot of the step function

yShift = fftshift(y) # shift of the step function
Fourier = scipy.fft(yShift) # Fourier transform of y implementing the FFT
Fourier = fftshift(Fourier) # inverse shift of the Fourier Transform
plt.plot(Fourier) # plot of the Fourier transform
```

Note that before and after applying the Fast Fourier Transform you have to use the fftshift command that provide a shift of the left side of the plot to the right side and viceversa.
This is not the complete answer to your question, but I believe that is a good start.

Comment: Could you give some details or references concerning on how to numerically deal with  Gamma(x) and exp(bx)? Thank you for your anwser

Comment: I believe that your function already starts from t = 0. If x is a python array, than xLeftSide = np.zeros(len(x)) x = np.append(xLeftSide, x) will generate an array two times longer than the previous one, in which all the values before t = 0 are zero and all the values after t = 0 are your function. This is the way in which I would manage the socalled "Gamma(x)". About the exponential I would say that the "b" parameter is the imaginary part of the complex parameter in Laplace Transform and it is usually used to avoid divergences in the integration, there shouldn't be much more to say.

Comment: I think the expression of the Laplace transformation (L) in terms for Fourier transformation (FT) is not correct.  The factor should be Gamma(x)f(x)exp(x(s+is)). The Fourier transformation already has a exp(i s t) which needs to be converted to exp(sx).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the **Trapezoidal rule** to calculate numerically the integral for the Laplace transform. One paper which describes this method is [Edward H. Hellen: Padé –Laplace analysis of signal averaged voltage decays obtained from a simple circuit](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233658371_Pade_-Laplace_analysis_of_signal_averaged_voltage_decays_obtained_from_a_simple_circuit) (Equation 2)

**Notes:**

1) "The summation approximates the integral in Eq. 1 [in the article] as long as the data are close to zero by the last data point."

2) "A good choice for p0 is the inverse of the time it takes for the
data to decay to 1/2 its initial value."

3) Since your data is not spaced equally, I would use interpolation (from scipy import interpolate) for the data first. The Trepozoidal rule needs equally spaced data.